# Using Nokogiri to validate XML: finding the line-nr of validation errors?

Tags: ruby, xml, validation, nokogiri

I am trying to validate pretty large XML files against a XSD-schema. Nokogiri does this perfectly fine, using the following code:

```
  xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read('batch_schema.xsd'))
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('batch205.xml'))

  xsd.validate(doc).each do |error|
    puts "#{error.line} :: #{error.message}"
  end
```

Simple enough. Only: `error.line` is always 65535. Because the XML files we need to check are really huge, it would be really, really, helpful to get the line-numbers.

I found this [XSD Validation cheatsheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet#xsd-validation) so that is where I found the option to read the line.

In the libxml2 documentation I found I have to *enable* line-numbers for it to be set. Any idea how to enable line-numbers with Nokogiri or get a line-number in a validation-error?

Comment: [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) comes with libxml2 and can handle huge files, along with validating them against an XSD. Nokogiri is going to read the entire "huge" XML file into memory, which isn't scalable, so you might want to look into xmllint.

Comment: Nope that is not true (anymore). If given a file, it will check the file and not load it into memory completely.

Comment: `File.read('batch205.xml')` will cause the entire file to be read into memory, per [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-read): "Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then returns length bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file).". That resulting string will be passed to Nokogiri. By default Nokogiri reads and parses the document into a DOM, which requires the entire tree to be in memory. Using Nokogiri::XML::SAX to parse the document node by node would act more like what you're talking about.

Comment: Ow good point! If I just write the filename instead, it will not load the entire file.  Anyway: that was not the issue and not the question at all. It validates the file in < 25s, I just need a line-number with the validation errors.

Comment: OMG @theTinMan that was totally it! If I just give the filename to the validation, not only is it quicker, but the line-nrs and columns are now correct! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to write it a little differently, instead of loading and parsing the entire xml upfront, I just needed to validate the file itself. Like so:

```
xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read('batch_schema.xsd'))

xsd.validate('batch205.xml').each do |error|
  puts "#{error.line} :: #{error.message}"
end
```